# SSIS not inserting records in the sorted order

Tags: ssis

I have written a SSIS pacakge for SQL Server 2008 R2 using Bids 2008 that contains dataflow task that will insert nearly 7 million records in the destination table. The problem that I am facing is that the records are not inserting in a sorted order in the destination table.  I have set the Keep identity ON and Fast Upload on the Oledb destination.
How to insert the  the records in the sorted order.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your question? Do you sort 7 million records in the dataflow, and the sort order is not preserved on insert? Or something else; it is still unclear from your question.

Comment: you want to copy data as it is order from source table ?

Comment: Yes.. It should copy data in same sort order as the source table

Comment: How do you know what order the records are inserted in?

Comment: how about indexing the destination?

Comment: I have indexed the table and everything looks ok now

Answer (score 1):

Though it is too late to answer but will be helpful for the others.

Don't use Fast Upload and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Either you sort them in your destination or else use add an index to the table in your desired order.